# How to Specifying More than one column for Disabling re-ordering in jQgrid?Code For Specifying one column?

Tags: jqgrid

How to specifying more than one column for disabling re-ordering in jQgrid?Code for specifying one column is below:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
 sortable:{
    exclude: '#'+ 'grid' +'_'+'columnname';
    //Specifying More than One Column
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `exclude` is just a selector. Thus one can specify multiple comma separated id selectors:

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    sortable: {
        exclude: '#' + 'grid' + '_' + 'columnname1' + ','
                 '#' + 'grid' + '_' + 'columnname2'
    }
);
```